# ColdFusion & Lotus Notes Calendar integration

Tags: coldfusion, lotus-notes

In an enterprise scenario where a ColdFusion application is used to register for a event, would it be possible to programmatically add an entry into the calendar of a person?

Google has given me some partial idea's like connecting via JDBC/ iCalendar, etc...

Any ideas & experiences are appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something I have seen in the past is that after the person has registered for the event, a link is given, something like:

> > [Click here to add this event to your calendar](http://foo)

The link goes to an .ical file, which Lotus Notes (as well as Outlook, and various other calendaring clients) can use to add the event to the user's calendar. You can create an iCal file using [CFiCalLib](http://cficallib.riaforge.org/).

Comment: Thanks Adam! Our team had sort of same idea, ie. sending an attachment to the user's email.  Any other suggestions please post!

Answer (score 1):

It's totally possible.

I've done a lot of direct Coldfusion - Notes integration in the past 12 years and the newer versions of Notes should have many integration points (scripts, agents, COM, etc) to create/edit calendar events.

Adam's angle might be good enough for you, I'd try that out.  If you're looking for something to be a little more direct (between the coldfusion and notes server directly, like sharepoint), there's options as well.

Comment: Jas, 

Please can you give me a working example ? 

Thanks for your time.